# How do I push data to a SQL server using Node.js and mssql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to send data to a SQL database using the mssql package for node.js, here is what I have so far:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
try {
    await sql.connect('mssql://<userid>:<userpassword>@<server>/<database>')
    const result = await sql.query("EXEC EXT_OP_GetData @Data1= '38', @Data2="+<some_data>+", @Data3="+<some_data>+", @ExtraData = 'Uploaded via stored procedure'")
    console.dir(result)
} catch (err) {
    // ... error checks
}
```

This does not upload the data to the SQL database, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your server MSSQL or MySQL? because if it's MSSQL then the MySQL connector will not work

Comment: @Jaxi yes microsoft sql server 2014

Comment: Then MySQL package won't work. use the mssql package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: @jaxi How can this be adapted to work for mssql?

Comment: The MySQL package cannot be used to talk to MSSQL. You must switch out your mysql package and install the mssql package. From there use the docs and it'll guide you through connecting.

Comment: @Sasha i realise that, I have mssql installed, but I'm not sure how to change the code to suit the package.

Comment: It has `Quick Example` on that page. that is how you use it

Comment: @Sasha i have tried following the documentation, it still doesn't upload. I have edited the question to show what I have tried

Comment: have you put anything in the catch? like a `console.error(err)`

Comment: @Sasha it returns `unknown driver defined` not sure what this means :/

Comment: You need to install a driver also. run `npm install tedious` to get the default driver

Comment: @sasha how do I implement the driver? I have imported it as `connection` shown in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195624/discussion-between-ecsync-and-sasha).